# background image in input form field to clear on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying this logic:

```
   $('input').on('click focusin', function() {
        $('.required').hide();
    });
```

But it doesn't seem to be working at all..

**This is what the mark-up looks like:**

```
<input type="text" name="Library" id="Library" placeholder="Email Address (again for verification)" data-name="E-mail Address Verification" class="required"/>
```

the CSS, basically I just want to hide this background image, rather background display none in jQuery / css chaining. or display none to the entire required field... but neither ideologies seem to work.

```
.field_holder .required {
    background: url("../images/required_field_star_bg.png") no-repeat;
    background-position: 11px 11px;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use the css `:focus` modifier? `input.required:focus { background-image: none; }`?

Comment: Do u want all the required class controls to hide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a psuedo class in CSS labelled `:focus` (as well as a `:required` and `:valid`) that allows you to change values for input elements that are in focus.

I have also amended your JavaScript, the issue is that the event you are looking for is simply called `focus` - you don't even need the `click` event for this! A `focus` is *always* 'into' the element anyhow.

Heres the code:

```js
$('input').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).css('border','1px solid red');
});
```

```css
input:required {
  background: url("http://placehold.it/200x200") no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
input:required:focus {
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="Library" id="Library" placeholder="Name" required />
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript/jquery for this, you could do it with pure css by using the `:focus` pseudo-class:

```
.field_holder .required {
    background: url("../images/required_field_star_bg.png") no-repeat;
    background-position: 11px 11px;
}

.field_holder .required:focus {
    background-image: none;
}
```